# How to decrease gap between elements without moving both of them

Tags: html, css

How can I move this "name" element without moving "surname" too?

https://prnt.sc/px23sk

I want "name" and "surname" in the same row, like you have on Facebook. I don't really understand positioning yet, but I have searched online and I still don't know to apply it on my example because of the many `div`s and content inside each other.

I added `float: left;` to my "name" element so it goes left, but when I try to add margin to make it go closer to "surname" it doesn't behave how I want.

Adding margin on `name-position` class also moves "surname" element right.

Here is my code: https://codepen.io/simic21/pen/zYYmbqz 
And this is the effect that I want: https://prnt.sc/px26ic

Comment: You need to put your markup and CSS here, in your question. The system should've notified you of that, but didn't because you included a few code strings. It's a basic requirement for posting on SO.

Comment: Yes but for people to understand i kinda have to put entire code but it's too long, isn't it? @isherwood

Comment: I doubt that's the case, but either way it doesn't change the rules. You're asking about two elements. So show the markup for two elements, along with the minimum number of  containing elements necessary to demonstrate the problem and the related CSS.

Comment: Okay, i will keep that in mind if i ask more questions. @isherwood

Answer (score 1):

Remove float and add `display: inline-block;` to divs for name and surname.

Comment: This one did the job - https://prnt.sc/pxckek .Thank you very much @step !

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
      <div class="form-content-inline">
        <label for="name" id="name-label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="ime" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-content-inline">
        <label for="surname" id="surname-label">Surname</label>
        <input type="text" id="surname" name="prezime" placeholder="Surname" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
```

```
.form-content, .form-content-inline {
  margin: 0 auto 1.25rem auto;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}
.form-content-inline {
  display: inline-block;
}
```